# R Shiny app runs out of memory when making predictions with multiple caret models

Tags: r, shiny, out-of-memory, r-caret, predict

I have 5 xgbTree models that were trained in caret and I want to use the same user input data to make a prediction with each model. So I need to load 5 rds objects and use the predict() function 5 times (once for each model). Each model is about 350,000-400,000 KB and the size of my data is 90,000 KB.

1. If I load the models at the beginning of the app outside of the server function I can make all 5 predictions locally but when I try to deploy it on shinyapps.io it disconnects saying "oom: out of memory" (this is with the instance size set to 3X-Large 8GB). I also tried trimming pieces of the models away to reduce the size.

```
trim_model_fun <- function(model) {
  model$trainingData <- NULL
  model$control <- NULL
  model$modelInfo <- NULL
  
  return(model)
}
```

2. If I load the models inside the server function, make a prediction, then delete the model I am able to run all 5 predictions on shinyapps.io but it takes 30 seconds to load the predictions.

```
# Predictions output:
  preds <- eventReactive(input$gobutton, {
    
    user_data <- df()
    
    # Sediment
    xgbTree_CEAP1and2_sed <- readRDS("xgbTree_CEAP1and2_sed_trimmed.rds")
    pred_sed <- ((predict(xgbTree_CEAP1and2_sed, newdata = user_data)*lambda_sed)+1)^(1/lambda_sed)
    remove(xgbTree_CEAP1and2_sed)
    
    # Surface Nitrogen
    xgbTree_CEAP1and2_SurfN <- readRDS("xgbTree_CEAP1and2_SurfN_trimmed.rds")
    pred_SurfN <- ((predict(xgbTree_CEAP1and2_SurfN, newdata = user_data)*lambda_SurfN)+1)^(1/lambda_SurfN)
    remove(xgbTree_CEAP1and2_SurfN)
    
    # Subsurface Nitrogen
    xgbTree_CEAP1and2_SubN <- readRDS("xgbTree_CEAP1and2_SubN_trimmed.rds")
    pred_SubN <- ((predict(xgbTree_CEAP1and2_SubN, newdata = user_data)*lambda_SubN)+1)^(1/lambda_SubN)
    remove(xgbTree_CEAP1and2_SubN)
    
    # Total Phosphorus
    xgbTree_CEAP1and2_P <- readRDS("xgbTree_CEAP1and2_P_trimmed.rds")
    pred_P <- ((predict(xgbTree_CEAP1and2_P, newdata = user_data)*lambda_TotalP)+1)^(1/lambda_TotalP)
    remove(xgbTree_CEAP1and2_P)
    
    # Soluble Phosphorus
    xgbTree_CEAP1and2_Psol <- readRDS("xgbTree_CEAP1and2_Psol_trimmed.rds")
    pred_Psol <- ((predict(xgbTree_CEAP1and2_Psol, newdata = user_data)*lambda_Psol)+1)^(1/lambda_Psol)
    remove(xgbTree_CEAP1and2_Psol)
    
    tibble(
      `Sediment (tons/acre)` = pred_sed,
      `Surface Nitrogen (lbs/acre)` = pred_SurfN,
      `Subsurface Nitrogen (lbs/acre)` = pred_SubN,
      `Total Phosphorus (lbs/acre)` = pred_P,
      `Soluble Phosphorus (lbs/acre)` = pred_Psol
    ) %>%
      mutate(`Sediment (tons/acre)` = round(`Sediment (tons/acre)`, digits = 1)) %>%
      mutate(across(`Surface Nitrogen (lbs/acre)`:`Soluble Phosphorus (lbs/acre)`, ~ round(., digits = 1)))
    
  })
```

Is there a way to load all of the models at the beginning of the app outside the server function and make the predictions on shinyapps.io without running out of memory? Or is my only option to load the models inside the server function and wait 30 seconds each time for predictions?